# Extracting subtitles from MKV files with ffmpeg or mplayer

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, matroska, mplayer

An MKV file containing multiple sets of subtitles refuses to play them on a SmartTV or similar devices, seeing no subtitles at all. mplayer manages the file without problems. Here's what is in the file:

```
$ ffprobe input.mkv |& grep Stream
Stream #0:0(zxx): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 716x360 [SAR 32:27 DAR 2864:1215], SAR 212:179 DAR 106:45, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Stream #0:1(spa): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s (default)
Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480 (default)
Stream #0:3(fre): Subtitle: subrip
Stream #0:4(por): Subtitle: subrip
```

My assumption is that less capable players are unable to cope with subtitle formats other than SRT. The question is, how does one extract the existing English subtitle track from the MKV file, convert it into SRT, and optionally, add it back into the MKV file.

Other than "I've never seen a MP4 file with SRT subtitles", another thread ([Converting DVD subtitles to text](https://superuser.com/questions/861645/converting-dvd-subtitles-to-text)) that asked the same question has not been answered.

The supposedly definitive https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ExtractSubtitles contains information that does not match the actual ffmpeg operation. This is my ffmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/man --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-avresample --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --disable-debug --disable-indev=jack --disable-outdev=jack --arch=x86_64 --enable-pic --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gnutls --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libsmbclient --enable-libwavpack
libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
```

And this is what I tried to do, without success:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:2 subs-EN.srt
...
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (dvd_subtitle (dvdsub) -> subrip (srt))
  Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
$ ffmpeg -codecs | grep dvdsub
...
DES... dvd_subtitle DVD subtitles (decoders: dvdsub ) (encoders: dvdsub )
```

So the dvdsub decoder is compiled into ffmpeg (as expected, or the subtitles would not show in mplayer), but is not being invoked to convert them.

I also tried

```
$ mplayer -dumpsrtsub -dumpfile subs-EN.srt -sid 0 input.mkv 
MPlayer 1.3.0-7.1.0 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
...
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (ac3), -aid 0, -alang spa
[lavf] stream 2: subtitle (dvdsub), -sid 0, -slang eng
[lavf] stream 3: subtitle (srt), -sid 1, -slang fre
[lavf] stream 4: subtitle (srt), -sid 2, -slang por
...
```

The correct subtitle stream is being played, but nothing gets written to subs-EN.srt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327919/5726027

Comment: I see. Thanks.  To summarize "dvdsub" is not a text-based subtitle format (surprising, because I can change the font that is used to render it), and needs OCR to convert it to srt. However, it can be "burned in" as an overlay on the video. Unfortunately, of the two commands you offer there, neither works very well:

    ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=input.mkv -acodec copy -sn converted.mkv

or

ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:2]overlay" -acodec copy -sn converted.mkv

Comment: **ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf subtitles=input.mkv -acodec copy -sn converted.mkv** complains No such filter: 'subtitles'

while 

**ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:2]overlay" -acodec copy -crf 20 -sn converted.mkv** produces terrible quality output.

Comment: *terrible quality output* --> the subtitles portion or the whole picture? If the latter, the pictures may have wayward sprites within its pixels and/or low-resolution. I would suggest the OCR route to text first. The subtitles filter requires `libass` to be compiled/linked.

Comment: The whole image, all blocky, as if a very limited video bandwidth.  In fact, adding **-crf 20** did not improve the quality much, if at all. There are some sprites (?) within the subtitles, and their resolution is also poor, but not critically so. I must say, you are the only person, on any forum, that seems to understand ffmpeg, a singularly idiosyncratic piece of software. Thanks for your patience, but you are light years ahead of the rest of us, trying to keep up. Is there an equivalent strategy within mplayer/mencoder? I seem to understand its logic better.

Comment: Does the same command, without the overlay, encode to acceptable quality? If yes, get a build with libass and try the subtitles filter. If not good, OCR is the only way left. `mplayer`, the original, is as good as abandonware, and I guess it uses the same decoder for dvdsub.

Comment: FFmpeg has had too many cooks. It's a 17 year old FOSS project with hacks, workarounds, accommodations for legacy API and ABI ..etc. So it's not surprising. Many of the codecs it implements are proprietary (reverse-engineered) or if standarized, have proprietary variants in the wild. I suspect other old FOSS projects with similarly large and diverse scopes will also have these issues

Comment: I have resolved my immediate problem by finding a .srt file of the English subtitles on the web. I am having difficulties finding Slackware package, so need to compile from scratch; might take me a while, and the motivation is now gone, as it seems a dead-end enhancement. Thanks again for your helpful suggestions, [https://superuser.com/users/114058/mulvya]