# How can I extract a subtitle in "HDMV PGS" format from a video with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, extract

I'm trying to extract a subtitle in "HDMV PGS" format embedded in a video with this command `ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.srt`  from [an answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/927507) command, but it gives the error

```
Error initalizing output stream 0:0 -- subtitle encoding only possible from text to text or bitmap to bitmap
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:3 -> #0:0 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgsub) -> ass (ssa))
        Last message repeated 1 times
```

as shown in the screenshot
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is no extraction though. As noted in the error, you can't convert bitmap subtitle to text subtiltle, unless you are using some [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)-ish converter (if such thing even exists).  If you really just want to extract as-is, add `-c:s copy`, or maybe use mkvtoolnix instead.

Comment: Related - https://superuser.com/questions/861645/converting-dvd-subtitles-to-text

Answer (score 0):

To **extract** these bitmap-subtitles, you can do it in 2 steps :

1 : `ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -map 0:s:0 -c:s dvdsub -f matroska subs.mkv`
2 : `mkvextract subs.mkv tracks 0:mysub`

and you'll get 2 files :
• mysub.idx   ← *index file*
• mysub.sub   ← *bitmap file*

*index file* contains the timestamps
*bitmap file* contains the bitmap subtitles

To **edit** *bitmap file*, you need OCR, like [SubtitleEdit](https://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit)

Comment: dvdsub is not the same thing as pgs though. The conversion will significantly reduces quality. And mkvextract can extract PGS from mkv files, AFAIK. (While on the other hand, some files might not have CodecPrivate for the dvdsub stream and mkvextract forbids you to extract such stream, as of today.)